# How to get the filepath and directory from a filename?

Tags: c#, .net

So I have this list of filenames.avi. each one comes from a different directory, path. I have a txt file of a list of those.

When they are all in the same folder thats easy, when I have each in one folder I must change the directory path accordingly for each file.

Thank you

Comment: `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(...)`

Comment: We need more details. What do you want to do? What do you have? What does the .txt file have?

Comment: how do you think this can be done? there may be more than one file with same filename, but in different directories, how do you plan to differentiate between them?

Comment: The text file is a list of file1.avi file2.avi file3.avi . Hope thats enough, sorry and thanks

Comment: string dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
string fileNameWithoutExtn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);

Comment: tried using  System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filename) but returns nothing

Comment: You'll have to perform a search for each file if you don't know where it is.

Comment: @JuannStrauss How can I do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use the `System.IO.Path` class.  The `Path.GetDirectoryName` will return the directory name (without a trailing '\' character).

There are other useful methods in the `Path` class, such as `GetFileName` and `GetExtension`.

Comment: but those are not working when I only have a filename, there seems to be a processes before it, search each file like @juann said, any ideas ?

Comment: Path.GetDirectoryName will return the path of the directory but only when you have the full or relative path to the file, if you have only filename you will get nothing, Path class basically only deals with provided strings, it doesn't search the filesystem.

Comment: I don't think you can do it efficiently but you can do it by searching through the file system. Check the answer!

Comment: "efficiently" would be to 1) narrow your search down to a movies folder. 2) search ALL files ("*.avi"). 3) iterate the list of filenames and test if it matches any of your filenames in your list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Directory.GetFiles()` method and search sub-directories. I recommend to narrow down the search because you will get Exceptions when accessing restricted folders, but generally you could use a method like the following one which will return the path to the first occurrence of the filename or will return `null`:

```
public string SearchFileSystem(string filename)
{
    string [] files = null;
    try
    {
         files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\", filename, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
    return files==null?null:files.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the file name

```
fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(file);
fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
```

and this will give you the file path

```
shortPath = fullPath.Substring(0, inputText.LastIndexOf("\"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sr = new StreamReader("filelist.txt");
while(!sr.EOF)
{
    string[] ListFiles = Directory.GetFiles("D:\movies\", 
                                            sr.ReadLine()/*your file name is the search pattern*/, 
                                            SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    if(ListFIles.Count > 0)
    {
        //File Found
        foreach(var f in ListFiles)
        {
            string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(file);
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
        }

    }

}
```